# merge mysql rows by name when names are slightly different

Tags: mysql, merge, rows

I'm trying to merge rows in MySQL using the following code:

```
SELECT
    type,
    name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(code SEPARATOR ',') AS code
FROM
    `table1`
WHERE
    name = '%name%' AND type = 'type'
GROUP BY
    name
```

However no changes to DB entries occur which is the first problem.

The database looks like this:

```
type | name  | code
-----|-------|-------
 A   | Milk2 | 143521
-----|-------|-------
 A   | Milk3 | 987564
-----|-------|-------
 B   | Oil   | 656435
-----|-------|-------
```

Which I'm trying to make look like:

```
type | name  | code
-----|-------|---------------
 A   | Milk  | 143521, 987564
-----|-------|---------------
 B   | Oil   | 656435
-----|-------|---------------
```

As you can see, names may be slightly different so this is another problem.
I am wondering whether there is any way to merge rows when, say the first four letters of the name match?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has several [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html) which might help.  There's LEFT(name, 4) and you might also want to look at SOUNDEX(name), which implements the [Soundex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) to hash words alike which sound alike.  For example:

```
 select soundex('smith'), soundex('smythe')

+ --------------------- + ---------------------- +
| soundex('smith')      | soundex('smythe')      |
+ --------------------- + ---------------------- +
| S530                  | S530                   |
+ --------------------- + ---------------------- +
1 rows
```

Or, using the example from your question:

```
select soundex('milk2'), soundex('milk3')

+ --------------------- + --------------------- +
| soundex('milk2')      | soundex('milk3')      |
+ --------------------- + --------------------- +
| M420                  | M420                  |
+ --------------------- + --------------------- +
1 rows
```

Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    type,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(name) SEPARATOR ',') AS name,  // note that since you've grouped on SOUNDEX(name) you can't just select name (MySQL may let you but will choose the first one
    GROUP_CONCAT(code SEPARATOR ',') AS code
FROM
    `table1`
WHERE
    name LIKE '%name%' AND type = 'type'
GROUP BY
    type, SOUNDEX(name)
```

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: `SOUNDEX` works the best here. No mistakes as far as I have checked. The only thing I wasn't able to fix is when, say "Oil" belongs to both Types A and B, then the codes are not merged.

Comment: If you don't need the type value in the merged set you could just leave that out - or, if you do need the type value, which one would you want to be associated with the merged result?  If you don't care too much which value is chosen, just leave "type," out of the group by and MySQL will (contrary to the SQL spec...) pick one value.  I'm not sure if it picks the first one it encounters or what, but that might work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `GROUP BY name` here, as the name is always different, and you need to use `LIKE` instead of `=` when using wildcards.

The following should give you the result you're looking for

```
SELECT 
 type , name, GROUP_CONCAT( code SEPARATOR  ',' ) AS all_codes
FROM  `table1` 
name LIKE '%name%' AND type = 'type'
```

Comment: That misses the point of the OP's request - e.g., to put milk2 and milk3 into the same bucket.

Comment: I tested this query on similar data and it throws exactly the result he is looking for

Comment: sadly 'LIKE' doesn't seem to be functioning properly when there is a lot of data. It tends to merge many codes that correspond to wrong names. It well could be me doing something wrong as well...

Comment: If you want the name at the beginning of the name field you can use `LIKE 'name%'` or if you want to have name as beninning of a word which is not the first word then use `LIKE '% name%'`